# How to ensure selected option value match the generated value from an equation with random variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: ed]

Is there a way I ensure that the selected value matches the generated value of an equation with random variable as seen at the bottom of the graph.
Object that stores data

```
        var STIIndexYearly = [
            {
                year: 1988,
                price: 1133.30
            },
          ...
            {
                year: 2019,
                price: 3153.73
            },
        ]
```

This is the code that generates the value

````
        var max = 31
        var min = 0
        var randomone = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
        var randomtwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - randomone + 1)) + randomone + 1;

        var equationpart1 = ((STIIndexYearly[randomtwo].price / STIIndexYearly[randomone].price));
        var equationpart2 = (("1" / (STIIndexYearly[randomtwo].year - STIIndexYearly[randomone].year)));

        var answer = (Math.pow(equationpart1, equationpart2) - 1)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using for loop, repeating the calculation again and again until the generated value matches the selected option value.

````
    var Yearly = $("#YearlyAmount").val()
    var Age = $("#AgeSlider").val()
    
    
    $("#form").on('change', function () {
        var LumpSum = $("#LumpSumAmount").val()
        var Yearly = $("#YearlyAmount").val()
        var Age = $("#AgeSlider").val()      
        var Years = 100 - Age
        var Capital = parseFloat(LumpSum) + parseFloat(Yearly) * parseFloat(Years)
        $("#info").html("Capital: " + Capital);
        console.log(Capital)
    });

    $("#calculator").click(function () {

        var max = 31
        var min = 0
        var x = document.getElementById("SelectedCompoundInterest").value;
        var duration = document.getElementById("SelectedDuration").value;
        var invested = document.getElementById("InvestedAmount").value;
        var limit = max - duration

        console.log(age);

        var min_x = parseFloat(x) - 0.025;
        var max_x = parseFloat(x) + 0.025;
        var randomone = Math.floor(Math.random() * (limit - min)) + min;
        var randomtwo = randomone + parseFloat(duration);
        var difference = randomtwo - randomone

        console.log(randomone, randomtwo)

        var answer;

        var a = 0
        while (true) {
            if ((answer >= min_x && answer < max_x && difference == duration) || a >= 10000)
                break;
            var difference = randomtwo - randomone
            var randomone = Math.floor(Math.random() * (limit - min)) + min;
            var randomtwo = randomone + parseFloat(duration);

            console.log('a: ' + a + ' ans: ' + answer + " min: " + min_x + " max: " + max_x);

            var equationpart1 = ((STIIndexYearly[randomtwo].price / STIIndexYearly[randomone].price));
            var equationpart2 = ((1 / (duration)));
            answer = (Math.pow(equationpart1, equationpart2) - 1)

            a++;
        }

        console.log('break;')
    });```
````